# Change Style from my Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs

I'm learning how to use the Ext.js framework and I'm building simple applications using the MVVM model. I built a simple Map and I'm trying to costumize it, I did an application using Google API and the GMapPanel widget, and now I would like to create a new style and add it but I'm having some issues adding my costume style.

I receive the the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
>       at constructor.init (MapController.js?_dc=20151109082919:198)
>       at new constructor (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:63176)
>       at constructor [as self] (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:12296)
>       at Object.widget (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:14662)
>       at constructor.create (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:26228)
>       at constructor.lookupComponent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:123938)
>       at constructor.prepareItems (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:124418)
>       at constructor.add (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:123436)
>       at constructor.initItems (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:123861)
>       at constructor.initComponent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:123821)

My code:

```
init: function () {

    var me = this,
        map = me.getView(), //Reference to map view
        store = map.getViewModel().getStore('Markers'), // Get the store from the ViewModel
        markers = [], // Create and empty markers array
        data;
    // Load the store
    store.load(function (records) {
        // Iterate through each record
        Ext.each(records, function (record) {
            data = record.getData(); // Get the data object from each record
            markers.push(data); // Push the objects onto the markers array
        });
    });
    map.markers = markers;  // Set the markers config for the Map component to the markers array

    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
        [
          {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]},
          {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#523735'}]},
          {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
          {
            featureType: 'administrative',
            elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
            stylers: [{color: '#c9b2a6'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
            elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
            stylers: [{color: '#dcd2be'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{color: '#ae9e90'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'landscape.natural',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'poi',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'poi',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{color: '#93817c'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'poi.park',
            elementType: 'geometry.fill',
            stylers: [{color: '#a5b076'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'poi.park',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{color: '#447530'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'road.arterial',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#fdfcf8'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'road.highway',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#f8c967'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'road.highway',
            elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
            stylers: [{color: '#e9bc62'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#e98d58'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
            elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
            stylers: [{color: '#db8555'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'road.local',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{color: '#806b63'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'transit.line',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'transit.line',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{color: '#8f7d77'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'transit.line',
            elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
            stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'transit.station',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'geometry.fill',
            stylers: [{color: '#b9d3c2'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{color: '#92998d'}]
          }
        ],
        {name: 'Styled Map'});


    map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the styles array to the gmappanel mapOptions object:

```
{
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'gmappanel',
    gmapType: 'map',
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.419824, -3.0509294),
    mapOptions: {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 15,
        styles: [
            {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#523735'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
            {
                featureType: 'administrative',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#c9b2a6'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#dcd2be'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#ae9e90'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'landscape.natural',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#93817c'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi.park',
                elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#a5b076'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi.park',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#447530'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.arterial',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#fdfcf8'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#f8c967'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#e9bc62'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#e98d58'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#db8555'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.local',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#806b63'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#8f7d77'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit.station',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#b9d3c2'}]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#92998d'}]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```